# Display (dry-run) revision numbers for Alembic migrations

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I can't seem to find some command that would display entire migration sequence  from start to finish without applying them.

Something like `alembic history` but in a "dry run" mode and for all of the revisions. Is such a thing available?

Comment: Isn't that just what `alembic history` does?

Comment: I doubt coz i am geting this error "alembic.util.exc.CommandError: Can't locate revision identified by '939bb1e647c8'".I checked the alembic history,939bb1e647c8 is not in the list